# How do I add a 'fill up' dot navigation style vertically on my html/css website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating my first html css website and would like to add a 'fill up' dot navigation style vertically on my page so my visitors know what page they are on.

Look at the website I have linked for clarification.

https://tympanus.net/Development/DotNavigationStyles/

I assume I should use js but I don't know how to actually code it into my website.

Here is my code for my website.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

<section id="home">
            <img id="derrick-ogole-logo" src="images/derrick-ogole-logo.png" alt="Derrick Ogole Official Logo">
        </section>
```

An example of my sections to indicate layout and page change.

CSS:

```
    .container{
    widows:100%;
    height:100%;
    /* CSS Smooth Scroll */
    overflow-y:scroll;
    scroll-behavior:smooth;
    scroll-snap-type:y mandatory;
}

.navbar{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.navbar ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    justify-content:center;
}

.navbar ul li{
    margin:0 1rem;
    padding:1rem;
}
```

What JS code do I add and how do I link it to HTML and CSS?

[image]

[image]

If I click the second dot, it fills up, goes to that page and then unfills but the first dot stays red (active) so their isn't a transition.

In my html for the dot:

```
<script src="dot-nav.js"></script>
```

In my js file

```
// listen for clicks on the navbar
document.querySelector('.navbar').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  // ignore it if the click isn't on an anchor element
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {

    // remove the 'active' class from all of the nav anchors
      document.querySelectorAll('.navbar a')
      .forEach(e => e.classList.remove('active'));

    // add the 'active' class to the clicked element
      e.target.classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

CSS for the dot:

```
    /* position the navbar center right */

.navbar{
    position:fixed;
    right:32px;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}


/* style the individual nav items */
.navbar a {
    /* make them little circles */
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    /* with some space between them */
    margin: 20px 0;

    /* hide the text content */
    text-indent: -999px;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* establish positioning conext for the ::after pseudo-elements (below)*/
    position: relative;
  }

  /* the "fill" */
.navbar a::after {
    /* won't render without a 'content' rule */
    content:""; 

    /* red fill */
    background-color: #ff0000;

    /* zero height until it's active */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;

    /* animate the height when it changes */
    transition: height 0.3s ease;
  }

  /* active and hovered elements */
.navbar a:hover::after,
.navbar a.active::after {
  /* change the height to 100%.
     the transition rule above will cause this to animate */
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your question should be more specific. What do you mean by a "sidebar dot navigation"? Do you have any examples on how it should work, not only how it should look?

Comment: I want to add the 'fill up' dot navigation style vertically on my page. Look at the website I have linked for clarification. https://tympanus.net/Development/DotNavigationStyles/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic implementation of what *i think* you're asking for.

The javascript is only there to add/remove the `active` css class. Everything is really happening in the CSS. I've added comments in the code to explain how it works, but feel free to hit me up if you have questions.

```js
// listen for clicks on the navbar
document.querySelector('.navbar').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  // ignore it if the click isn't on an anchor element
 if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
  
    // remove the 'active' class from all of the nav anchors
   document.querySelectorAll('.navbar a')
      .forEach(e => e.classList.remove('active'));
      
    // add the 'active' class to the clicked element
   e.target.classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* position the navbar center right */
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 32px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* style the individual nav items */
.navbar a {
  /* make them little circles */
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
  /* with some space between them */
  margin: 20px 0;
  
  /* hide the text content */
  text-indent: -999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* establish positioning conext for the ::after pseudo-elements (below)*/
  position: relative;
}

/* the "fill" */
.navbar a::after {
  /* won't render without a 'content' rule */
  content: ''; 
  
  /* white fill */
  background-color: #fff;

  /* zero height until it's active */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;

  /* animate the height when it changes */
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

/* active and hovered elements */
.navbar a:hover::after,
.navbar a.active::after {
  /* change the height to 100%.
     the transition rule above will cause this to animate */
  height: 100%;
}

/* make the sections occupy the full screen height */
section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
  color: bisque;  
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="home">home</section>
  <section id="about">about</section>
  <section id="services">service</section>
  <section id="contact">contact</section>
</div>
```

Comment: A few things.  I have linked my html to my js file named: dot-nav.js file 

<script src="dot-nav.js"></script>

However, I am unclear as to how to add html classes and ids to my js file because I have managed to get the fill up navigation above but it's horizontal rather than vertical. Also, when I click another page, the home dot is still active but doesn't transition because of I haven't added js properly. 

I am also unsure what content rule to put in here too.

 /* the "fill" */
.navbar a::after {
    /* won't render without a 'content' rule */
    content:"";

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "how to add html classes and ids to my js file". What ids/classes do you need to add? The home dot is active in my example because it's hard-coded to have the "active" class. If you're navigating between pages, flag the appropriate nav item accordingly. You don't have to put anything in the content rule. It just has to be present for the ::after rule to work.

Comment: I added the js code, css code for the dot the link to my js.file  in my question description. If I activate all the navbar links html with active classes, all the dots stay red. If I activate only the first dot it stays red but doesn't go when I click a dot corresponding to another page. However, the clicked dot for my second, third or fourth page fills up for a second when clicked but doesn't stay filled once I reach that page - only the active first page dot stays red. Refer to my added description for more information.